# Ruby: How to safely require all classes in a directory at once?

Tags: ruby, require

In `Ruby` I can require all class files in a directory at once:

```
Dir["/path/to/directory/*.rb"].each {|file| require file }
```

But what if the classes have inheritance relationships? How to avoid requiring the subclass before superclass? (or it's impossible?)

Comment: If files itself mantain correct `require` dependencies everything will be OK, otherwise it's roulette.

Comment: so have you tried autoload, does it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a dirty hack, suppose you've named all your files correspond to class names.  But this approach works only if you have just **inheritance relationships** between different classes.  **Method overriding** multiple times is not taken into account.

Let's say you have two rb files in the to be required directory: *engineer.rb* and *human.rb*.

-- *engineer.rb*

```
class Engineer < Human
end
```

-- *human.rb*

```
class Human
end
```

And in another file which is gonna require them, if you specify engineer first you'll get an error:

```
require 'engineer' #=> uninitialized constant Human (NameError)
require 'human'
```

So we can simply play with the powerful weapon **autoload**:

```
Dir['/path/to/directory/*.rb'].each do |f|
  module_name = /\/([^\/\.]+?)\.rb$/.match(f)[1].capitalize.to_sym
  autoload(module_name, f)
end

#=> autoload :Engineer, 'engineer'
#=> autoload :Human, 'human'

puts Engineer.new #=> #<Engineer:0x007f91728847e8>
```

Basically autoload will require file on demand, thus the sequence of requiring is no more a problem.

If you want to know more about autoload, please check here:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-autoload
http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-techniques-revealed-autoload-1652.html

But please be aware that autoload will be dead soon (because it's not thread safe), please refer to here (by Matz):
http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3036681